# Changes in POJO are not reflecting in JSON payload in java

Tags: java, json, rest, pojo, payload

I am using POJO to create a JSON message for API input. Some of the fields from the JSON message were in lower case and I changed them to upper case but when I log the payload it the fields are still in lower case. Changes are not applied somehow.

I tried rebuilding , invalidating cache, deleting older builds and removing target file.

The fields in question are , DED, MOP,MPP,LFE and SCR.
What am I missing ?

Below is the child POJO

```
package com.domanirx.automation.adjudication.adjcpe.commerc.accum.pojos.AccumCalcWrite;


public class AccumCopayDetails {


   private DED DED;
   private MOP MOP;
   private MPP MPP;
   private LFE LFE;
   private SCR SCR;



   public AccumCopayDetails(com.domanirx.automation.adjudication.adjcpe.commerc.accum.pojos.AccumCalcWrite.DED DED, com.domanirx.automation.adjudication.adjcpe.commerc.accum.pojos.AccumCalcWrite.MOP MOP, com.domanirx.automation.adjudication.adjcpe.commerc.accum.pojos.AccumCalcWrite.MPP MPP, com.domanirx.automation.adjudication.adjcpe.commerc.accum.pojos.AccumCalcWrite.LFE LFE, com.domanirx.automation.adjudication.adjcpe.commerc.accum.pojos.AccumCalcWrite.SCR SCR) {
       this.DED = DED;
       this.MOP = MOP;
       this.MPP = MPP;
       this.LFE = LFE;
       this.SCR = SCR;
   }


   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return "AccumCopayDetails{" +
               "DED=" + DED +
               ", MOP=" + MOP +
               ", MPP=" + MPP +
               ", LFE=" + LFE +
               ", SCR=" + SCR +
               '}';
   }


   public com.domanirx.automation.adjudication.adjcpe.commerc.accum.pojos.AccumCalcWrite.DED getDED() {
       return DED;
   }


   public void setDED(com.domanirx.automation.adjudication.adjcpe.commerc.accum.pojos.AccumCalcWrite.DED DED) {
       this.DED = DED;
   }
```

Parent/Main POJO

```
package com.domanirx.automation.adjudication.adjcpe.commerc.accum.pojos.AccumCalcWrite;


import com.domanirx.automation.adjudication.adjcpe.commerc.accum.pojos.CSR.HimClaimPricingDetails;


public class AccumWriteInput {
   private ClaimCore claimCore;
   private PricingSegment pricingSegment;
   private ClaimPricingDetails claimPricingDetails;
   private AccumCopayDetails accumCopayDetails;
   private InsuranceSegment insuranceSegment;
   private String schema;
   private String caseId;
   private String medicalRxIndicator;
   private String networkIndicator;
   private String retailMailOrderIndicator;
   private String brandGenericIndicator;




   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return "AccumWriteInput{" +
               "claimCore=" + claimCore +
               ", pricingSegment=" + pricingSegment +
               ", claimPricingDetails=" + claimPricingDetails +
               ", accumCopayDetails=" + accumCopayDetails +
               ", insuranceSegment=" + insuranceSegment +
               ", schema='" + schema + '\'' +
               ", caseId='" + caseId + '\'' +
               ", medicalRxIndicator='" + medicalRxIndicator + '\'' +
               ", networkIndicator='" + networkIndicator + '\'' +
               ", retailMailOrderIndicator='" + retailMailOrderIndicator + '\'' +
               ", brandGenericIndicator='" + brandGenericIndicator + '\'' +
               '}';
   }
```

This is where the POJO is called and used as payload

```
ClaimCore claimCore = new ClaimCore(1625, 1, 33, 779, 659, "2016-01-10", "000000021284450100");
   InsuranceSegment insuranceSegment = new InsuranceSegment(
           "21284450100", "GLORIA", "DELGADO", "P1234567", 1,
           "33", "00", 1, "MO", "Y");


   DED DED = new DED("D", 0, 0, 0, 0, " ");
   MOP MOP = new MOP("D", 0, 0, 0, 0, " ");
   MPP MPP = new MPP("D", 0, 0, 0, 0, " ");
   LFE LFE = new LFE("D", 0, 0, 0, 0, " ");
   SCR SCR = new SCR("D", 0, 0, 0, 0, " ");


   AccumCopayDetails accumCopayDetails = new AccumCopayDetails(DED, MOP, MPP, LFE, SCR);


   PricingSegment pricingSegment = new PricingSegment(300.00, 0, 300.00);
   com.domanirx.automation.adjudication.adjcpe.commerc.accum.pojos.AccumCalcWrite.ClaimPricingDetails claimPricingDetails = new com.domanirx.automation.adjudication.adjcpe.commerc.accum.pojos.AccumCalcWrite.ClaimPricingDetails(
           100.00, 100.00, 0.00,
           200.00, 0.00,
           0.00, 0.00,
           0.00, 0.00,
           0.16, 100.00, "B",
           0.00, 0.00);


   AccumWriteInput accumWriteInput = new AccumWriteInput(claimCore, pricingSegment, claimPricingDetails, accumCopayDetails, insuranceSegment,
           " ", "000000000212844501", "P", "I", "R", "G");


   S68_1Response = SerenityRest.given().auth().oauth2(DomaniRx_RestAssuredOAuth2.access_token_code)
           .header("platform", "DR2")
           .contentType("application/json")
           .header("Accept", "application/json")
           .log().body()
           .body(accumWriteInput)
           .post(accumWrite)
           .then()
           .statusCode(200)
           .extract().response();


}
```

Below is the product/payload that is logged and the words in question are still lower case: MOP,MPP,DED,LFE,SCR

```
"accumCopayDetails": {
        "mop": {
            "copayUsedType": "D",
            "accumulatorMetCopay": 0,
            "accumulatorMetCoinsurance": 0,
            "accumulatorMetMinimumCopay": 0,
            "accumulatorMetMaximumCopay": 0,
            "accumulatorMetCopayType": " "
        },
        "mpp": {
            "copayUsedType": "D",
            "accumulatorMetCopay": 0,
            "accumulatorMetCoinsurance": 0,
            "accumulatorMetMinimumCopay": 0,
            "accumulatorMetMaximumCopay": 0,
            "accumulatorMetCopayType": " "
        },
        "ded": {
            "copayUsedType": "D",
            "accumulatorMetCopay": 0,
            "accumulatorMetCoinsurance": 0,
            "accumulatorMetMinimumCopay": 0,
            "accumulatorMetMaximumCopay": 0,
            "accumulatorMetCopayType": " "
        },
        "scr": {
            "copayUsedType": "D",
            "accumulatorMetCopay": 0,
            "accumulatorMetCoinsurance": 0,
            "accumulatorMetMinimumCopay": 0,
            "accumulatorMetMaximumCopay": 0,
            "accumulatorMetCopayType": " "
        },
        "lfe": {
            "copayUsedType": "D",
            "accumulatorMetCopay": 0,
            "accumulatorMetCoinsurance": 0,
            "accumulatorMetMinimumCopay": 0,
            "accumulatorMetMaximumCopay": 0,
            "accumulatorMetCopayType": " "
        }
    },
```

Comment: How are you "logging" it? Also, please delete as much code as possible from your question unless it's absolutely required to describe your problem. For example, all the `toString()` methods can be deleted because they are irrelevant. Please make an effort to curate the code you share to so the community doesn't have to wade through reams of irrelevant code to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The default naming strategy that Jackson uses is `LOWER_CAMEL_CASE` which would explain why chaning the name of the object properties is not reflected in the output json. Also it's not a very good practice to have all uppercase properties unless they're constants so in your case I'd suggest using the `@JsonProperty(value=<your-value>)` annotation.